# Custom post template makes my wordpress crash

Tags: wordpress

I have created a custom post type "toornament" in my wp.
I have done a single-toornament.php in my plugin.
When i require it in my index.php, i have a fatal error...
Maybe it can be a pot configurating erro ? I give you the code below.

Do you know where it can be from ?

```
<?php
function toornament_post() {


// Set UI labels for Custom Post Type
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Toornaments', 'Post Type General Name', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Toornament', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Toornaments', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Parent Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'All Toornaments', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'View Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Add New Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Add New', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Edit Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Update Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Search Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Not Found', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Not found in Trash', 'twentytwenty' ),
    );
     
// Set other options for Custom Post Type
     
    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Toornament', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Toornament information et inscription', 'twentytwenty' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
        /* A hierarchical CPT is like Pages and can have
        * Parent and child items. A non-hierarchical CPT
        * is like Posts.
        */ 
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'query_var'           => 'toornament',
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        'show_in_rest' => true,
 
    );
     
    // Registering your Custom Post Type
    register_post_type( 'toornament', $args );
 
}
```

I have add this :

```
    function get_custom_post_type_template( $single_template ) {
    global $post;

    if ( 'toornament' === $post->post_type ) {
        $single_template = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/single-toornament.php';
    }

    return $single_template;
}
add_filter( 'single_template', 'get_custom_post_type_template' )
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to set up the template for your CPT in functions.php - if you set up your template correctly, it will be picked up automatically by WP. To save yourself a lot of trouble, I suggest you learn the basic about how templates work in Wordpress before going any further: [Wordpress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)

Comment: thats only correct if your template is in the theme folder...if it is in a plugin folder (like by the question creator) wordpress will not recognize the template

Answer (score 0):

if you create single-{post-type}.php template you should not include it to the index.php

For adding a single template for your Custom Post Type there are two ways:

1. Copy it to your Child-Theme
2. hook it via `single_template` filter hook. [here you will find how to do it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/custom-post-type-templates-from-plugin-folder)

your code to create a new Custom Post Type from your question works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, i have had a part of code following the second option but it causes a wp fatal error... Do you know where it can come from ? (i have edited the post)

Comment: thx for new information....please add the error message to your question...maybe you must activate the debugging file in your wordpress wp-config.php (https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/ )...i dont want to write a plugin to solve your problem ;-)

at first glance i guess that the path does not match the file